# Не заботают "mysqli" теги в php 7.2, как решыть?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

У меня проблема! Не работают теги для подключения к mysql через php. Локальный сервер поднят на docker. Вот код:

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "password", "dostavka", 3306);

if (!$link) {
    echo "Ошибка: Невозможно установить соединение с MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Код ошибки errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Текст ошибки error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
    exit;
}

echo "Соединение с MySQL установлено!" . PHP_EOL;
echo "Информация о сервере: " . mysqli_get_host_info($link) . PHP_EOL;

mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

После строки "$link = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "password", "dostavka", 3306);" дальше док не работает и ничего не выводится. В чем проблема???

Comment: `var_dump($link);die;` после $link что показывает

Comment: Я решил проблему. Нужно било в докерфайле дял PHP добавить ето:
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli \
    && docker-php-ext-configure mysqli \
    && docker-php-ext-configure pdo_mysql